# three.js give grey color on edges when camera far from a mesh

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I made the floor in blender and aligned up perfectly without overlap and gaps and bake texture, when importing everything works fine, but on the floor, between planks, I get gray lines. (all planks are separate meshes). how do rid of this grey color? [image]

[image]